# What event order does Firebase guarantee for non-write operations?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

The firebase documentation contains an Event Guarantee for write operations: "Writes from a single client will always be written to the server and broadcast out to other users in-order."

However I did not found any information about non-write operations, i.e. read or auth events.
I think about the following use case:

Access to my Firebase DB needs to be authenticated, so on application initialization I would do:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
ref.authWithPassword({
  "email": "bobtony@firebase.com",
  "password": "correcthorsebatterystaple"
```

}

Then if the first HTML has to be rendered, the needed data will be fetched from Firebase:

```
ref.once("value", function(data) {
  // do some stuff once
});
```

So my application guarantees that the authentication call happens before the retrieving of data.

Does Firebase guarantee that the authentication is done before the read takes place? Or can it be that the read will fail with a permission error because the initialization has not yet finished?

Answer (score 0):

There are no such guarantees, nor are they needed. You can use a completion listener on the `authWithPassword()` call to get the ordering guarantee. From the [Firebase documentation for `authWithPassword()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/authwithpassword.html):

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
ref.authWithPassword({
  "email": "bobtony@firebase.com",
  "password": "correcthorsebatterystaple"
}, function(error, authData) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Login Failed!", error);
  } else {
    console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
  }
});
```

You could attach your `once()` listener in that last `else` block.

Similarly you can use an `onAuth()` listener for when the authentication happens (or the state changes). From the [Firebase documentation for `onAuth()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/onauth.html):

```
ref.onAuth(function(authData) {
  if (authData) {
    console.log("Authenticated with uid:", authData.uid);
  } else {
    console.log("Client unauthenticated.")
  }
});
```

Here again, you'd attach your listener in the `else` block.

The difference between the two samples is that the first callback only fires when the user is actively authenticated, while the second also fires on for example a page reload. Which one to use, depends on your app.

Comment: Yes, I know about the listeners, but I'm quite unsure how to bring this listener stuff into my application architecture. I'm using Angular the user can directly access different HTML pages. So if he accesses a page the first time, the Angular framwork is started up - that's where I would do the authentication. Angular then continues processing and finally renders the view the user want to see - so there in the controller I would then retrieve the data. So from the application design point, these two actions are very far from each other. How could this be handled in gooad architectural way?

Comment: Just to clarify to my comment above: authentication is done using a technical user, so it can be done without user interaction.

Comment: Going further the road: there should at least be a guarantee if I mix read and write operations. So if I first call set() on an node and then read it later using once(), it should be guaranteed that I see the changes I made before. Is this guaranteed? So If the order of write/read operations is guaranteed, why is there no such guarantee for the order of read/read operations?

Comment: A client will always see its own writes. But authentication is neither a read nor a write. It's a call to a different service, which has its own flow. What if the remote OAuth server is taking a long time to respond? Should database reads be blocked? For your scenario the answer seems to be "yes", but that does not apply to all use-cases.

Comment: Your use-case is solved with completion listeners. In the case of AngularFire, there is a method called `$waitForAuth()` for that. You might also use `$onAuth()` or an auth gate in a router. See Your use-case is solved with completion listeners